# What can be saved before factory reset?

Tags: backup, factory-reset

My phone has a GPS problem and service says the need to wipe it completely.
They are probably just lazy and would rather do it the easy way.
C'est la vie.

The phone is SGS unrooted 2.3.4 - Touch Wiz. I don't want to root it.

Now, what I am going to do is this:
- Save contacts with Kies
- Save files

Is there anything else I can do or that I should know?

For example, I believe that apps associated with the Google Account will be reinstalled after I re-enter my account into the newly formatted phone, correct?
However, app data like savegames won't be ported, I have to search for them in the phone memory?

Can I backup SMS?

Can I back-up settings?

Will imported contacts keep all fields like I have them now, i.e. work phone, home phone, work email, home email etc?

I know it's a ton of questions, sorry about that.
Thank you.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you can back up everything which has a "data provider" available -- as e.g. contacts, call-logs, SMS, and the like. If you search the playstore for "backup", it will give you a lot of apps for that. One of the best non-root backup solutions for this probably is [MyBackup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rerware.android.MyBackupPro), which covers most of it -- though there are a lot of apps offering to backup/restore parts.

Most other app's data cannot be backed-up, however. Some of them provide possibilities to export their settings (and import them at a later point), others have dedicated backup apps (I remember e.g. something like that for *Angry Birds*).

For contacts and calendar, there's also the possibility to sync them with your Google account. I would not, however, rely on the "Google backup" for other things, as it is often reported to unsuccessfully restore. For that case, there are extra measures one can take. The easiest would be to logon to [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/) with your Google credentials, and sync your installed apps. Appbrain then allows you to save that as a list with their service: you can then use this list to restore all apps you put into it -- or you could even send it to a different device (even a different user's device) for a "mass install".

In case you had some apps installed which are no longer available on the playstore, you could also take a look at [AppMonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager): in its payed (pro) version, it also allows batch-install. Plus, it captures each app you install/update and saves a copy -- which can be useful in the future as well: if some update breaks a functionality, you can ask *AppMonster* to simply restore a previous (captured) version.

And though this *currently* does not affect you (as your Android version is lower than 4.0), just to mention for other users (and your possible future device): starting with Android 4.0, there is the possibility for a [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices) (rooted users always have this possibility with [Titanium Backup ★ root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)).

Data stored on your sd card should not be affected by the factory-reset.

Comment: I would recommend you remove the external SD card before sending, and backup the internal.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. How about apps? Will they be reinstalled on the device when I first log in on the new install? Or do I have to pick them up by hand, one-by-one?

Comment: Depends on. If you enabled Google Backup ("Do you want to backup your data to Google...") before (and after the factory reset), they *theoretically* should be restored on the first sync. *Practically*, however, it often seems to fail. So in that case, you had to install them manually. Or, alternatively, login to [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/) before resetting, and sync with them. Login thereafter and let your list restore. Just in case the Google backup stuff fails.

Comment: Guess I'll move those "extra chars" up to the answer itself, as it is a means of "backup your apps".

Comment: By "extra chars" I meant, the char limit for comments is stupid.

Comment: I noticed. Saw the added chars in the answer? Count them, and count the chars from the corresponding comment as well to compare #-) Never mind, got it :)